# Combinations of Nested Lists

Tags: python, list, nested, combinations

I have three lists that are generated by other functions. Let's assume for now they are:

```
x = ['d', 'e']
g = ['1', '2']
y = ['f', g]
```

As you can see, `g` is part of `y`. I am trying to get all combinations of the elements of the three lists. I have tried going about this in two ways:

One way:

```
l = []
l.append([a]+[b] for a in x for b in y)
```

Another way using itertools:

```
import itertools
l = list(itertools.product([a for a in x], [b for b in y]))
```

Both ways produce the following combinations:

```
[('d', 'f'), ('d', ['1', '2']), ('e', 'f'), ('e', ['1', '2'])]
```

But what I would like to get is:

```
[('d', 'f'), ('d', '1'), ('d','2'), ('e', 'f'), ('e', '1'), ('e','2')]
```

Also, when `x` for example is empty, I get no combinations at all when I am still expecting to get the element combinations of the remaining two lists.

Comment: Why don't you just flatten y first and then use `itertools.product`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is inspired from @Psidoms answer but just uses a specifically tailored `flatten` function to make sure only items that should be flattened are iterated:

```
def flatten(x, types=list):
    lst = []
    for item in x:
        if isinstance(item, types):
            for subitem in item:
                lst.append(subitem)
        else:
            lst.append(item)
    return lst

>>> from itertools import product

>>> list(product(x, flatten(y)))
[('d', 'f'), ('d', '1'), ('d', '2'), ('e', 'f'), ('e', '1'), ('e', '2')]
```

Note that there is unfortunatly no such `flatten` function in the standard library but you could also use one from an external library, for example [`iteration_utilities.deepflatten`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/deepflatten.html). Note that this requires to provide `str` or `basestring` as `ignore`:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import deepflatten

>>> list(product(x, deepflatten(y, ignore=str)))
[('d', 'f'), ('d', '1'), ('d', '2'), ('e', 'f'), ('e', '1'), ('e', '2')]
```

---

To exclude empty iterables from the product simply exclude empty subiterables. For example:

```
>>> x = []
>>> iterables = [subiterable for subiterable in (x, list(deepflatten(y, ignore=str))) if subiterable]
>>> list(product(*iterables))
[('f',), ('1',), ('2',)]
```

Comment: Beat me to it :) I think it might be desirable to check if `item` inherits from the abstract base class `abc.Iterable`, then make sure it's not a string, then pull the elements into the top level.  That would let us get things out of generators, maps, tuples, etc...

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yeah, I think determining the types or excludes could be better but I already did that once [`iteration_utilities.deepflatten`](http://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/cfuncs.html#iteration_utilities.deepflatten) (a pure python implementation can be found at the bottom of that function docstring), no need to repeat it again. :-)

Answer (score 6):

As @BrenBarn commented, you can flatten list `y` with `chain` function, and then use `product`:

```
from itertools import product, chain

list(product(x, chain.from_iterable(y)))
# [('d', 'f'), ('d', '1'), ('d', '2'), ('e', 'f'), ('e', '1'), ('e', '2')]
```

Comment: It's just great that even single character strings are iterable, otherwise this wouldn't work! I wish I had a (up-)vote left.

Comment: @MSeifert Right, if the elements are int/float, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Be aware that if you change `y = ['fall', g]`, or some other multiple character string, it displays potentially undesirable behaviour

Comment: @PatrickHaugh True, I am wondering if there is a general `flatten` method that can discriminate between strings and other iterable such as list/tuple/dictionary. Or you just have to be always careful about it.

Comment: Thank you all for the answer and comments. But how do you deal with the case when x is an empty list?

Comment: It seems to me that when x is empty, `product` also returns an empty list. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Psidon. Well, I just brought `x` as an example, I was wondering about getting the combinations from other lists when one is empty. It seems that, just as @MSeifert said, I have to exclude empty iterables from the product.

Comment: Yeah. What I mean is that it's not really a product anymore, since for a product, the result is a combination of elements from each input list, if one input list is empty, by definition, the result should also be empty. But if that is what you need, then I guess practice is more than definition.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out two implementations for flatten-like functions available in [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) (install via `pip install more_itertools`).

[`flatten`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.flatten) is an [`itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) and emulates @Psidom's proposal:

```
import itertools as it
import more_itertools as mit

list(it.product(x, mit.flatten(y)))
# [('d', 'f'), ('d', '1'), ('d', '2'), ('e', 'f'), ('e', '1'), ('e', '2')]
```

However, for flattening more deeply nested iterables, consider using [`collapse`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.collapse):

```
# Example
x = ['d', 'e']
g = [('1'), [[['2']]]]
y = [{'f'}, g]

# Bad
list(it.product(x, mit.flatten(y)))
# [('d', 'f'), ('d', '1'), ('d', [[['2']]]), ('e', 'f'), ('e', '1'), ('e', [[['2']]])]

# Good
list(it.product(x, mit.collapse(y)))
# [('d', 'f'), ('d', '1'), ('d', '2'), ('e', 'f'), ('e', '1'), ('e', '2')]
```

Comment: Nice alternative with `more_itertools.collapse` but strangly this is slower than using the pure-python implementation I've presented in [`iteration_utilities.deepflatten`](http://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/cfuncs.html#iteration_utilities.deepflatten) and much slower than using `iteration_utilities.deepflatten` itself. Maybe there is some room for improvement!

Comment: @MSeifert Perhaps there is room for improvement, but what do you consider "much slower"? I ran Jupyter's `%timeit` command on both `mit.collapse(y)` and `iteration_utilities.deepflatten(y)` and got ~700 ns for each. What times did you observe? Also, I found `collapse` flattened deeply nested iterables, e.g. `[[1], 2, [[3], 4], [[[5]]], 'abc']` as is, without keywords, which may be a reasonable tradeoff.

Comment: both return generators, so did you cast them to lists or otherwise iterate over them? Because I get 15us for `collapse` and 4us for `deepflatten`. However, the difference get's bigger if the iterables get longer.

Comment: You're right about the "no need for additional keywords", however I consider it somewhat of a drawback not being able to flatten strings (even if only optionally). But in the end it doesn't matter. I was just surprised about the time difference. :-)

Comment: Yes I can reproduce your value by timing a list comprehension with `collapse`, but my computer stops responding if I attempt a similar process for `deepflatten`.  I welcome suggestions.  An aside, how would you apply  `deepflatten` to `[[1], 2, [[3], 4], [[[5]]], 'abc']`?

Comment: hehe, that could be a good new question (would be nice to give `more-itertools` and `iteration_utilities` some more attention) :-) But it depends if you want to flatten the string, then you need to specify a `depth` (the actual value doesn't matter, it just needs to be large enough to flatten everything but below the recursion limit): `list(deepflatten(lst, depth=5))` or if you want to keep it as-is then `ignore` strings: `list(deepflatten(lst, ignore=str))`

Comment: Aha.  Success!  Nice options with `deepflatten`.